Dynamically create Entity,DbSet,Migration file,Migrator file and Tables
I want to dynamically generate the following components based on user input properties:
Entity Class: Create a C# class representing the entity with properties based on user input.
DbSet: Add a DbSet property to the DbContext for the newly created entity.
Migration File: Generate a migration file that includes the necessary schema changes for the new entity.
Migrator File: Implement a migrator to handle the migration process and ensure the database schema is updated accordingly.
The properties for the new entity will be specified in a dictionary like this:
var properties = new Dictionary<string, Type>
{
    { "Name", typeof(string) },
    { "CreatedDate", typeof(DateTime) }
};

Using this dictionary, the system should:
Create an entity class with properties matching the dictionary entries.
Update the DbContext to include a DbSet for the new entity.
Generate a migration file that reflects the schema changes for the new entity.
Apply the migration to the database to ensure that the table is created or updated with the specified columns.
While I tried using this code
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

public static class DynamicTypeBuilder
{
    public static Type CreateDynamicType(string className, Dictionary<string, Type> properties)
    {
        var typeBuilder = GetTypeBuilder(className);
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            CreateProperty(typeBuilder, property.Key, property.Value);
        }
        return typeBuilder.CreateTypeInfo().AsType();
    }

    private static TypeBuilder GetTypeBuilder(string className)
    {
        var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(className);
        var assemblyBuilder = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(assemblyName, AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
        var moduleBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("MainModule");
        return moduleBuilder.DefineType(className, TypeAttributes.Public | TypeAttributes.Class);
    }

    private static void CreateProperty(TypeBuilder typeBuilder, string propertyName, Type propertyType)
    {
        var fieldBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineField($"_{propertyName}", propertyType, FieldAttributes.Private);
        var propertyBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineProperty(propertyName, PropertyAttributes.HasDefault, propertyType, null);

        var getterMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod($"get_{propertyName}", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, propertyType, Type.EmptyTypes);
        var getterIl = getterMethod.GetILGenerator();
        getterIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        getterIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, fieldBuilder);
        getterIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        var setterMethod = typeBuilder.DefineMethod($"set_{propertyName}", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.SpecialName | MethodAttributes.HideBySig, null, new[] { propertyType });
        var setterIl = setterMethod.GetILGenerator();
        setterIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        setterIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        setterIl.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, fieldBuilder);
        setterIl.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

        propertyBuilder.SetGetMethod(getterMethod);
        propertyBuilder.SetSetMethod(setterMethod);
    }
}
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class DynamicDbContext : DbContext
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Type> _entityTypes;

    public DynamicDbContext(DbContextOptions<DynamicDbContext> options, IEnumerable<Type> entityTypes)
        : base(options)
    {
        _entityTypes = entityTypes;
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in _entityTypes)
        {
            modelBuilder.Model.AddEntityType(entityType);
        }

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}

public class DynamicModelCustomizer : ModelCustomizer
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<Type> _entityTypes;

    public DynamicModelCustomizer(ModelCustomizerDependencies dependencies, IEnumerable<Type> entityTypes)
        : base(dependencies)
    {
        _entityTypes = entityTypes;
    }

    public override void Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
    {
        foreach (var entityType in _entityTypes)
        {
            modelBuilder.Model.AddEntityType(entityType);
        }

        base.Customize(modelBuilder, context);
    }
}
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public class MigrationService
{
    private readonly IMigrator _migrator;
    private readonly DynamicDbContext _context;

    public MigrationService(IMigrator migrator, DynamicDbContext context)
    {
        _migrator = migrator;
        _context = context;
    }

    public void Migrate()
    {
        _context.Database.Migrate();
    }

    public async Task ApplyMigrationsAsync()
    {
        var pendingMigrations = await _context.Database.GetPendingMigrationsAsync();
        foreach (var migration in pendingMigrations)
        {
            await _migrator.MigrateAsync(migration);
        }
    }
}
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();
        ConfigureServices(serviceCollection);

        var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();
        using (var scope = serviceProvider.CreateScope())
        {
            var migrationService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MigrationService>();
            migrationService.Migrate();
            await migrationService.ApplyMigrationsAsync();

            // Insert data to test if tables are created and functioning
            var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<DynamicDbContext>();
            InsertTestData(context);
        }
    }

    private static void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var entityTypes = new List<Type>();

        // Define dynamic entities
        var dynamicEntities = GetDynamicEntities();

        foreach (var entity in dynamicEntities)
        {
            var type = DynamicTypeBuilder.CreateDynamicType(entity.Key, entity.Value);
            entityTypes.Add(type);
        }

        services.AddSingleton(entityTypes);

        services.AddDbContext<DynamicDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer("YourConnectionStringHere")
                   .ReplaceService<IModelCustomizer, DynamicModelCustomizer>());

        services.AddScoped(provider =>
        {
            var options = provider.GetRequiredService<DbContextOptions<DynamicDbContext>>();
            var entityTypes = provider.GetRequiredService<IEnumerable<Type>>();
            return new DynamicDbContext(options, entityTypes);
        });

        services.AddScoped<IMigrator>(provider =>
        {
            var context = provider.GetRequiredService<DynamicDbContext>();
            return context.Database.GetService<IMigrator>();
        });

        services.AddScoped<MigrationService>();
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Type>> GetDynamicEntities()
    {
        return new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, Type>>
        {
            {
                "DynamicEntity1", new Dictionary<string, Type>
                {
                    { "Id", typeof(int) },
                    { "Name", typeof(string) }
                }
            },
            {
                "DynamicEntity2", new Dictionary<string, Type>
                {
                    { "Id", typeof(int) },
                    { "Description", typeof(string) }
                }
            }
        };
    }

    private static void InsertTestData(DynamicDbContext context)
    {
        var dynamicEntity1Type = context.Model.FindEntityType("DynamicEntity1").ClrType;
        var dynamicEntity2Type = context.Model.FindEntityType("DynamicEntity2").ClrType;

        var dynamicEntity1 = Activator.CreateInstance(dynamicEntity1Type);
        var dynamicEntity2 = Activator.CreateInstance(dynamicEntity2Type);

        dynamicEntity1Type.GetProperty("Id").SetValue(dynamicEntity1, 1);
        dynamicEntity1Type.GetProperty("Name").SetValue(dynamicEntity1, "Test Name");

        dynamicEntity2Type.GetProperty("Id").SetValue(dynamicEntity2, 1);
        dynamicEntity2Type.GetProperty("Description").SetValue(dynamicEntity2, "Test Description");

        context.Add(dynamicEntity1);
        context.Add(dynamicEntity2);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
} 


the migration history table is being created, but it's not populated with migration entries. Additionally, the table for the new entity is not being created in the database.

OnModelCreating is called ONLY ONCE per class type DynamicDbContext. So your solution will not work, second time _entityTypes will be not used. You have to prepare Model sperately from DbContext something like that
